# SPARK Integer overflow check

Tags: ada, ada2012, spark-2014

I have the following program:

```vhdl
procedure Main with SPARK_Mode is
   F : array (0 .. 10) of Integer := (0, 1, others => 0);
begin
   for I in 2 .. F'Last loop
      F (I) := F (I - 1) + F (I - 2);
   end loop;
end Main;
```

If I run `gnatprove`, I get the following result, pointing to the `+` sign:

> medium: overflow check might fail

Does this mean that `F (I - 1)` could be equal to `Integer'Last`, and adding anything to that would overflow? If so, then is it not clear from the flow of the program that this is impossible? Or do I need to specify this with a contract? If not, then what does it mean?

---

A counterexample shows that indeed `gnatprove` in this case worries about the edges of `Integer`:

> medium: overflow check might fail (e.g. when `F = (1 => -1, others => -2147483648)` and `I = 2`)

Comment: Could one claim that `F (I) <= 2 * I` for all `I`?

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen, I think that would be true as long as `I <= 7`, and would be false otherwise.

Comment: Ahh.  Yes.  I can't remember the convergence limit for this series, but I'm sure it is possible to look it up somewhere.  The trick is to convince your provers that it is correct.  The easy solution would be to have `gnatprove` unroll the loop before passing it to the provers.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen, how can I do that? Also, wouldn't that present a problem if the upper limit of `F` would come from user input instead of being the constant `10`?

Comment: I think loop-unrolling is controlled by some command line parameter.  And no, loop-unrolling wouldn't work if the range is dynamic.  Then you have to know your math.

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding a loop invariant to your code. The following is an example from the book "Building High Integrity Applications with Spark".

```vhdl
procedure Copy_Into(Buffer : out Buffer_Type;
                    Source : in String) is
   Characters_To_Copy : Buffer.Count_Type := Maximum_Buffer_Size;
begin
   Buffer := (Others => ' '); -- Initialize to all blanks
   if Source'Length < Characters_To_Copy then
      Characters_To_Copy := Source'Length;
   end if;
   for Index in Buffer.Count_Type range 1..Characters_To_Copy loop
      pragma Loop_Invariant
        (Characters_To_Copy <= Source'Length and
         Characters_To_Copy = Characters_To_Copy'Loop_Entry);
      Buffer (Index) := Source(Source'First + (Index - 1));
   end loop;
end Copy_Into;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how I could use a `Loop_Invariant` for this. Can you please post an example?

Comment: Every trip around the loop, you change the contents of `F`.  You have to help the tools, but telling them something which doesn't change about `F` by taking one more trip around the loop.  (Newer versions of the SPARK tools can be told to unroll short loops, thus avoiding having to think about loop invariants.)

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen, hmm, I'm thinking that the only thing that changes is the value of `F (I)`, everything else remains the same. Still, I'm not sure what I could express in a loop invariant to help the tool.

Answer (score 2):

This is already an old question, but I would like to add an answer anyway (just for future reference).

With the advancement of provers, the example as stated in the question now proves out-the-box in GNAT CE 2019 (i.e. no loop invariant needed). A somewhat more advanced example can also be proven:

**main.adb**

```vhdl
procedure Main with SPARK_Mode is

   --  NOTE: The theoretical upper bound for N is 46 as
   --
   --              Fib (46)    <    2**31 - 1    <    Fib (47)
   --           1_836_311_903  <  2_147_483_647  <  2_971_215_073

   --  NOTE: Proved with Z3 only. Z3 is pretty good in arithmetic. Additional
   --        options for gnatprove:
   --
   --           --prover=Z3 --steps=0 --timeout=10 --report=all

   type Seq is array (Natural range <>) of Natural;

   function Fibonacci (N : Natural) return Seq with
     Pre  =>  (N in 2 .. 46),
     Post =>  (Fibonacci'Result (0) = 0)
     and then (Fibonacci'Result (1) = 1)
     and then (for all I in 2 .. N =>
                Fibonacci'Result (I) = Fibonacci'Result (I - 1) + Fibonacci'Result (I - 2));

   ---------------
   -- Fibonacci --
   ---------------

   function Fibonacci (N : Natural) return Seq is
      F : Seq (0 .. N) := (0, 1, others => 0);
   begin

      for I in 2 .. N loop

         F (I) := F (I - 1) + F (I - 2);

         pragma Loop_Invariant
           (for all J in 2 .. I =>
              F (J) = F (J - 1) + F (J - 2));

         --  NOTE: The loop invariant below helps the prover to proof the
         --        absence of overflow. It "reminds" the prover that all values
         --        from iteration 3 onwards are strictly monotonically increasing.
         --        Hence, if absence of overflow is proven in this iteration,
         --        then absence is proven for all previous iterations.

         pragma Loop_Invariant
           (for all J in 3 .. I =>
              F (J) > F (J - 1));

      end loop;

      return F;

   end Fibonacci;

begin
   null;
end Main;
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop invariant should work - since 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) < 2^n - but I can't convince the provers:

```vhdl
procedure Fibonacci with SPARK_Mode is
   F : array (0 .. 10) of Natural := (0      => 0,
                                      1      => 1,
                                      others => 0);
begin
   for I in 2 .. F'Last loop
      pragma Loop_Invariant
        (for all J in F'Range => F (J) < 2 ** J);

      F (I) := F (I - 1) + F (I - 2);
   end loop;
end Fibonacci;
```

You can probably convince the provers with a bit of manual assistance (showing how 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) = 2^(n-2) * (2 + 1) = 3/4 * 2^n < 2^n).